# C# Windows.Forms converting code to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagridview

I am trying to convert my Windows Form program into a WPF program in order to get images in my NotifyIcon systemtray icon. I am having issues converting it though. My current program has a tabcontrol1 and it uses the function: TabPages and DrawItem. WPF does not have these functions, but instead of TabPages it has Items, but I do not know what to change "DrawItem" to for WPF.

The reason why I am using "DrawItem" in my Windows Form is to change the color of the Tab text.

[image: Plus and minus next to the options.]

Changing from:

```
      if (!find<T>(p.Value))
      {
         T myPage = new T();
         myPage.Text = "Ping";
         this.FormstabControl.TabPages.Add(myPage);
         this.FormstabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ListBox1_DrawItem);                            
         myPage.DataGridView.DataSource = p.Result;
      }
```

To:

```
      if (!find<T>(p.Value))
      {
         T myPage = new T();
         myPage.Text = "Ping";
         this.WPFtabControl.Items.Add(myPage);
         //this.WPFtabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ListBox1_DrawItem);                            
         myPage.DataGridView.DataSource = p.Result;
       }
```

I had to comment out DrawItem because I do not know what to use instead. Also, type "T" is of type "TabPages" not Item. Below is the Find function that checks to see if the Tab already exists in the tabcontrol. When I declare myPage of type T, it setsup the DataGridView from within a different class (same as where T is defined.) I tried to fix it by throwing the WPF TabControl1 into a Windows.Form TabControl2, then searching through that tabcontrol's tabpages instead of passing a WPF Tabcontrol Item.

```
    private bool find<T>()
    {
        bool found = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.TabControl FormstabControl= new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        FormstabControl.TabPages.Add(this.WPFtabControl.Items.ToString());
        foreach (TabPage page in FormstabControl.TabPages)
        {
            if (page is T)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    private bool find<T>(string text) where T : TabPage
    {
        bool found = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.TabControl FormstabControl= new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        FormstabControl.TabPages.Add(this.WPFtabControl.Items.ToString());
        foreach (TabPage page in FormstabControl.TabPages)
        {
            if (page is T && text.Equals(page.Text))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

When I run this app and the adjacent function, it runs and completes and adds a BLANK text tab, but returns no data to the datagrid within the TabControl. I do not know what is wrong.

How can I incorporate images in my NotifyIcon? I incorporate it like this:

```
  this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
  this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Hide", new EventHandler(hideApp)));
  this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Show", new EventHandler(showApp)));
  this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(exitApp)));
```

Comment: In WPF, you should write most of your GUI directly in XAML. The full power of WPF is that you can abstract (almost) all of your GUI creation to your XAML. May I ask why you want to change the color of the Text? If you want to disable it, you should just use `enabled="false"`.

Comment: That is going to be tough because 80% of my code is already in Windows.Forms. :(

Comment: WinForms and WPF are simply not compatible... you cannot convert the code line by line as you are trying to do. If someone correctly created a WPF application that looked like an exact copy of your WinForms application, you would probably not recognise more than a few sections of code in it. Even if you actually managed to do this, you'd end up with a poorly written WPF application that doesn't take advantage of what WPF offers.

Comment: Darn, it was worth a shot then. Thank you.

Comment: @user2216791 this is why I constantly discourage people from using winforms, which is a completely useless and deprecated technology. If your current app was in WPF, you could have reused that in many other technologies (WinRT XAML, Silverlight, Windows Phone) with very few changes. Even if you wanted to move to a completely different framework (such as Android) you could actually reuse part of the code, because WPF encourages separation of UI and application  / presentation logic. But instead of that, you're now stuck with non-portable, non-scalable useless winforms code. That's just sad =(

Comment: How can I incorporate images in my NotifyIcon? I set it up based off the above in original post.